# object is leaking. NSAutorelease pool

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

i got an message at my log file (GDB) as object is leaking...
NsAutorelease pool.. like something nearly for 10 times.
Can anyone explain me. why this message is displaying..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably because it is leaking.. Could you show the code that is around this NSAutoreleasePool? That way we might be able to tell you.

Comment: Short Answer: Why? Its leaking. Now for a detailed answer actually post the console message and/or related/suspected code.

Comment: In the future, it would be best to post the actual error you're getting rather than a garbled recollection like "object is leaking… NsAutorelease pool… like something." If this hadn't been such an obvious and well-known error, nobody would have been able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally use:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

// Your autoreleased objects

[pool release];
```

But it depends on where in your code you're running in to the issue... Are you using multi-threading? Or is everything happening in the main thread?

Comment: Use `[pool drain]` instead of `[pool release]`

Answer (score 3):

It means you are autoreleasing objects with no autorelease pool in place. So those objects are not being released, and are probably leaking as a result.

So you should make sure you have a pool in place.